# regex search left to right?

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> test1 = "123 main street, slc, utah county, utah 84115"  # test string
>>> address_end_pattern3 = re.compile(r"\b((ut(ah)?)\,?[\s\n](84\d{3}(\-\d{4})?)|(84\d{3}(\-\d{4})?)|(ut(ah)?))\b", re.IGNORECASE) # all 3 patterns concatenated with | in the order I would like it to be found
>>> address_end_pattern2 = re.compile(r"\b((ut(ah)?)\,?[\s\n](84\d{3}(\-\d{4})?)|(84\d{3}(\-\d{4})?))\b", re.IGNORECASE)  # 2 patterns omitting the state only pattern
>>> address_end_pattern1 = re.compile(r"\b(ut(ah)?)\,?[\s\n](84\d{3}(\-\d{4})?)\b", re.IGNORECASE)  # the first pattern (state and zip) alone
>>> address_end_pattern1.search(test1).group()
'utah 84115'  # it finds the first pattern correctly when it is the only pattern
>>> address_end_pattern3.search(test1).group()  # but not when the state only pattern is there
'utah'
>>> address_end_pattern2.search(test1).group()
'utah 84115'  # finds the first pattern when combined with zip alone
```

After a previous question confirmed it, I believe regex searches string and pattern left to right... but then this happened. If it finds that pattern correctly by itself, and also when concatenated with zip pattern, why does it only find the state pattern when that is the last option in the concatenated pattern? Can anyone explain this behavior?

EDIT:
for clarity, the pattern which is the best indicator of the end of an address if the first pattern:

```
r"\b(ut(ah)?)\,?[\s\n](84\d{3}(\-\d{4})?)\b" # with re.IGNORECASE
```

I am trying to identify something like:
UT, 84115
or
Utah, 84115-0001

If that doesn't occur, then just a zip code is my next best option to identify the end of an address:

```
r"\b(84\d{3}(\-\d{4})?))\b"
```

Which should match something like:

84115 
or
84115-0011

Then finally, if neither matches then I want to look for just the state:

\b(ut(ah)?)\b

which should match:
UT 
or 
Utah

I want to find it in that order because the last two might either cut off some information or in various cases consume the second address which might be listed because the address is listed as:

1234 main st, slc UT and 1235 main st, slc UT 84115

Comment: Your long and complicated patterns are making it difficult for me to understand your issue. Can you distil things down a bit? If I'm following things properly, you're confused about why the pattern `ab|a` matches only `a` in the text `a ab`. Is that right?

Comment: @Blckknght Pattern 1 is looking for an occurrence of state and zip code, pattern 2 concatenates pattern one (with or operand |) with a pattern looking just for zip code. Then pattern 3 adds a pattern just for state with last 2 patterns also using |.  I will break down each pattern further now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex matches `utah` in `utah county` due to your 3rd option in your 3rd pattern. Since it comes before your desired "utah 84115", that's your first match, `utah 84115` being the second. If you switch around "utah 84115" and "utah county", it works. https://regex101.com/r/zQ4rJ1/5 .

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, your example seems to be doing this because of the greedy `.*`. I am not using that in my regex. Or am I off base here?

Comment: In your example, it matches the last test string with the first occurrence of 'test'.

Comment: So it doesn't scan the entire string for each pattern one at a time, it is some strange combination of checking each pattern against each section of the string as it moves down the string?

Comment: Dunno if I'd call it a strange combination, but yes - checking patterns as you move down the string. You have to take in account how the program or regex would "read" it.

Comment: It would seem as though I should compile each individually and run separate searches to get the results I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but if you use `findall` instead of `search` this should return a list of all the matches you are looking for.

```
address_end_pattern3.findall(test1)
```

I am not certain, but I assume your issue has to do with the interaction between how `re.search` works and how `|` works.

Comment: findall is not what I am looking for, because of certain instances where multiple addresses occur and the off chance a street number might match a zip... among other things

Answer (score 1):

A regex search always finds the match in a text that starts first. For your example pattern, that's the `"utah"` part of `"utah county"`. If multiple alternatives in the pattern can be matched starting at the same character, it picks the alternative in the pattern (the left side of the `|`), which may not be the longest. When using `search` (rather than `findall`), the rest of the text is never even examined, so there's no way to get a later match instead.

Your example pattern and text can be boiled down to a much simpler example, which might help you play around with it and understand what's happening. Here `a` is a stand in for "utah" (which appears twice in the text) and `b` is a standin for a zip code (which appears just once).

```
>>> re.search('ab|a|b', 'a ab').group()
'a'
```

Comment: I see that makes sense. So it starts the search at the first occurrence of the first part of the first pattern, then tries all `or` versions to find a match from that spot?

Comment: do the parentheses cause that?